# PayPal - Selling a single app

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

I would like to sell a desktop application over my website through PayPal. The user will receive a download link and a license key.
Are there any PHP scripts availabe from PayPal IPN to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Hundreds... Narrow your question down by providing us details what the website is running on (such as content management system).

Comment: This is not the proper place for this question. It is not a recommendation or suggestion engine. This sort of question is better suited for [chat]. See [about StackOverflow](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/about).